# If I have a List<T>, is there any advantage of using an IEnumerable<T> when looping through the list?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

In C#, if I have a `List<T>`, that is stored in an object, and I want to check if a value exists in the list, is there any advantage of calling a function that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than looping through the `List<T>` that I already have?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're checking if a value exists, why are you calling a function that returns an IEnumerable<T>?  Sounds like you should be calling Contains() which returns a boolean.

Comment: What `IEnumerable` is this other function returning, and how does obtaining another `IEnumerable` relate to finding a value in a list?

Comment: Too hard to tell without any code samples. :-/. The main difference is IEnumerable is readonly and IList is not. but in your case that should not matter.

Comment: I think that they are same

Comment: Please edit your question to include code samples illustrating the function that you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a read operation that you're describing. Return your `IList<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Then, use linq's [`Contains()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1241) - which internally check for implementation of `ICollection` and optimize to the use the implementation available, despite that fact that it accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`. In other words, you lose nothing by returning an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

when you return the property as `IEnumerable<T>`, that tells the caller that you can not mutate the value of it, you can just iterator it, that can help you get rid of lots of unexpected error.

if you expose the property as `List<T>`, it can be easily mutated by "others", this can cause a mess in a large system, so keep your data as immutatable as possible.

image you are tracking a bug because the item in the list is not currect, if the property is exposed as List, you have to look into all the usage of that property to see who changed it, but if you you exposed it as Iemumerable, you can be sure that the only place to change it is the object it self, that will save you a lot of time to tracking the bug.

Answer (score 0):

List is a mutable collection - you can add to, remove from  and sort it etc. It is  flexible  but IEnumerable allows you to use the same code to work with any implementation  of arrays, linked lists, lists, iterators returned from methods using yield statements.